# Securing a directory with htaccess in a virtual hosting

Tags: .htaccess, hosting, virtual

I use the below .htaccess in a directory in my web root to restrict public access to its files:

.htaccess

```
<Limit GET POST>
order deny,allow
deny from all
allow from 127.0.0.1
</Limit>
```

But the problem is that my website is hosted in a virtual hosting environment, so is there any concern that someone hosting his files in the same server that I'm using can have access to these files (since we all fall under 127.0.0.1)?

Answer (score 1):

You are right, someone from the same host can access that Directory. If you want to make it secure, i would recommend to set a password.

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Protected Area"
AuthUserFile /home/www/path/to/.htpasswd
require valid-user
```

Create an .htaccess file using htpasswd -c .htpasswd yourusername or use one of the online htaccess password generators online.

> `<Limit GET POST>`

Also, do never use something like that if you are not sure you want to restrict **only** POST and GET. Apache offers more than that, i.e. HEAD, PUT, DELETE, CONNECT methods to make Requests.

> [The purpose of the <Limit> directive is to restrict the effect of the
>   access controls to the nominated HTTP methods.](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#limit)

Skip the <Limit> to be sure.